# как получить новый массив объектов из массива JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть массивы:

```
products = [
   {id:1, name:'product1', price:100},
   {id:2, name:'product2', price:200},
   {id:4, name:'product3', price:300},
   {id:5, name:'product1', price:400},
   {id:6, name:'product2', price:500},
   {id:7, name:'product3', price:600},
];
ids_products_in_cart = [2, 5, 7];
```

Нужно создать новый массив с элементами `id` в `ids_products_in_cart`, используя `products`, и изменить его, чтобы получилось:

```
var newArray = [
   {id:2, name:'product2', quantity_in_cart:1},
   {id:5, name:'product5', quantity_in_cart:1},
   {id:7, name:'product3', quantity_in_cart:1},
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const newArray = products.filter(product => ids_products_in_cart.includes(product.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const products = [
   {id:1, name:'product1', price:100},
   {id:2, name:'product2', price:200},
   {id:4, name:'product3', price:300},
   {id:5, name:'product1', price:400},
   {id:6, name:'product2', price:500},
   {id:7, name:'product3', price:600},
];
const ids_products_in_cart = [2, 5, 7];

const result = ids_products_in_cart.reduce((res, id) => {
  const item = res.find((_) => _.id === id);
  item ? item.quantity_in_cart++ : res.push({ id, name: products.find((_) => _.id === id).name, quantity_in_cart: 1 });
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```